# Migrate SVN repository with 30 projects to GIT: 30 GIT repositories?

Tags: git, svn

Migrate SVN one repository with 30 projects to GIT: do I need to create 30 GIT repositories, one for each svn project?

For backup, svn hotcopy can backup the whole svn repository containing 30 projects. How about GIT? Is there a quick way to backup 30 GIT repositories?

Can GIT manage 30 repositories as one like group?

Comment: You can certainly place tons of SVN repos into a single git repo. There are pros & cons for combining projects. You can read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monorepo. If you are migrating from SVN often it is very important to check if you binary files check in. These are technically possible in git, but binaries should have their own place such as git-lfs. There are many migration guides on the web.

Comment: Though I agree with @tomwaitforitmy on the core of his comment (and I have upvoted it), I want to bring up that it is ok to put binary files in git, even if it is not _designed_ to handle them.... the problem is that providers like github have a fixed limit on the size of a given blob that can be pushed into their repos, which is 100 MBs (github, at least)... which, these days, doesn't sounds like too high a limit for a given binary file and then using git-lfs becomes a must in order to handle them if you wan to use the provider...

Comment: .... repos that you handle yourselves do not have such a problem given that git places no limit on the size of a blob... and if it does (which I am not sure it does), it certainly is not 100 MBs.

Comment: Just because it is possible doesn't always mean that it makes sense. Git is especially for tracking differences line by line. If you have a small change inside a binary, the whole file changes. Furthermore, the way git works, the file will always be in your history. Forever, because it is not easy to undo history. At least for me, that's definitely not what  I want for large files. I want my repo to be a small as possible for performance. But yes, you are certainly right. It is possible and it can make sense for small files or files that (almost) never change.

Comment: Not really trying to antagonize with you, @tomwaitforitmy. I think we agree on the core idea. However, want to check on this:`Git is especially for tracking differences line by line`. git **does not** keep diffs between commits. Every single time, it's a full snapshot of every file that makes up the commit you are creating (of course, no need to redo work for files that haven't changed, right?). It this regard, binary files or text files are not handled differently by git: they are compressed (in full)  and added into the object DB _but_ no diffing takes place....

Comment: ... then, when you run a `git diff`between 2 commits (for instance), git takes the _trees_ of both commits and diffs them _on the fly_.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely right. I don't we actually disagree on many points. You wanted to emphasize that it is possible and it works. I wanted to emphasize that it may not be the best idea to check in huge files. From my experience, it is also a "bad" idea in SVN, because you have the same disadvantages like in git (slow clones, binary diffs are not readable for humans etc.), however, many people in SVN did in the past and it was "best practice", because of no other available, easy to use option. Committing binary files might be an easy option in git, but there are alternatives.